# How to create UnsafePointer<CGRect> from existing CGRect

Tags: swift, cocoa, cgrect, unsafe-pointers

How to create UnsafePointer? 
Trying let mediaBoxPtr = UnsafePointer(mediaBox) but fails

```
func PDFImageData(filter: QuartzFilter?) -> NSData? {
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    let consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(pdfData);
    var mediaBox =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
    let mediaBoxPtr : UnsafePointer<CGRect> = nil //???? I need CGRect(x:0, y:0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)
    if let pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, mediaBoxPtr, nil) {
      filter?.applyToContext(pdfContext)}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create a pointer. Simply pass the address of the `mediaBox` 
variable as "inout argument" with `&`:

```
var mediaBox =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
if let pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, &mediaBox, nil) {
    // ...
}
```

For more information and examples, see ["Interacting with C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17):

> Mutable Pointers
>
> When a function is declared as taking an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>`
>   argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - An in-out expression that contains a mutable variable, property, or subscript reference of type `Type`, which is passed as a pointer to the address of the mutable value.
> - ...

Comment: Thanks, tried this but it failed to compile, now it works as a charm (I found this answer previously). The important part is to use var instead of let. I know...